# jquery get checkboxes, all having the same class, based on links

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, twig

I'm having an initial AJAX request, which brings in some extra html and a bunch of checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user-responses[]" class="js-answer-check question1" data-question="1" data-option-id="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="user-responses[]" class="js-answer-check question1" data-question="1" data-option-id="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="user-responses[]" class="js-answer-check question1" data-question="1" data-option-id="3">
```

Then, I'm having some generated links using Twig templating engine.

```
<a href="" class="quiz-questions" data-question="1" data-quiz="4">1</a>
<a href="" class="quiz-questions" data-question="2" data-quiz="4">2</a>    
<a href="" class="quiz-questions" data-question="3" data-quiz="4">3</a>    
<a href="" class="quiz-questions" data-question="4" data-quiz="4">4</a>    
<a href="" class="quiz-questions" data-question="5" data-quiz="4">5</a>    
<a href="" class="quiz-questions" data-question="6" data-quiz="4">6</a>
```

If the link with text 1 will be clicked, another AJAX request will bring in the same checkboxes as above.

If, lets say, the link with text 3 will be clicked, then the generated checkboxes is the following (replacing the above checkboxes):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user-responses[]" class="js-answer-check question3" data-question="3" data-option-id="7">
<input type="checkbox" name="user-responses[]" class="js-answer-check question3" data-question="3" data-option-id="8">
<input type="checkbox" name="user-responses[]" class="js-answer-check question3" data-question="3" data-option-id="9">
```

What I want, using jquery, is that when I click `<a ...>1</a>` to get an array of those checkboxes that have `class="question1"` and are checked, and when I click a link like `<a ...>3</a>` to get an array of checkboxes that have `class="question3"` and are checked.

My app is about quizzes, so I'm using AJAX requests to get the question text, the question options (as checkboxes), and I'm having a quiz navigator, which contains the links for each question.

If an user navigate to a question, checks some checkboxes, and submits the answer, I want the checked checkboxes to stay checked. This is already done.

The problem is that, because of those checkboxes who remains checked, I get extra values for my array collection.

To be specific, if I press `<a ...>1</a>` and if I check both checkboxes with `class="question1" data-option-id="1"` and `class="question1" data-option-id="2"`, and send data through AJAX, on success, both ckeckboxes stays checked, and the array is `[1, 2]`. Then, if I click `<a ...>3</a>` and if I check the checkbox with `class="question3" data-option-id="7"`, then my array will contain the previous values too, and instead of containing just `[7]`, it is `[1, 2, 7]`.

Ajax code when checking a checkbox:

```
var optionsArr = [];
var questionID;
$(document).on('click', '.js-answer-check', function(e){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        questionID = $(this).data('question');
        var optionID = $(this).data('id');
        optionsArr.push(optionID);
    } else {
        var removeItem = $(this).data('id');
        optionsArr = $.grep(optionsArr, function(value){
            return value != removeItem;
        });
    }
});
```

How can I prevent that from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clear the optionsArr before sending the AJAX request each time so that you don't send duplicate data. You can simply do this before adding data to the options:

optionsArr = [];

Or better yet, just declare a local array in that function instead of making it a global variable:

var optionsArr = []; (and delete the global one)